# Connecting a bulb and a buzzer onto the same output of a relay

Tags: arduino-uno, buzzer

I am currently doing a project to light up a bulb and a buzzer at the same time. This circuit is an Arduino UNO which is connected to a relay to light up a bulb and the buzzer.

Can a 40 watt bulb and a 240V buzzer be connected to the same output of the relay to power them as in the image below?

[image]

My circuit is currently like this.  How can I add in a 240V buzzer through this circuit?

**My Equipment**

1. Arduino UNO
2. Resistor 100 ohm
3. Jumper wires
4. 40 watt light bulb
5. Short breadboard
6. Relay (5VDC , 10A 250VAC, 15A 125VAC, 10A 250VAC)
7. A 240V alarm to be installed into the circuit.

Comment: Not without specs, datasheet links and a real schematic

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Hi Sir, I've added the equipments I used but Im not sure if its what you requested.

Comment: What's the voltage of the 40W bulb? Are the voltages you mention AC or DC? Are all those just mains voltage devices?

Comment: I expected you to include datasheets like this https://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet.pdf  also for {so called} 240 V buzzer and bulb and input voltage is not specified but looks like a 120V plug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is 120V, right? Add 120/240 transformer, 120V side (or 0 - 120V tap) parallel with the bulb. Connect the buzzer on 240V side (or 0 - 240V tap) of the transformer. Whatever you do, be safe.

Comment: I'd assume the OP is in 240 volt land - if so, the buzzer and light can simply be connected in parallel.  If he is in 120 volt territory, then a transformer would be required for the buzzer.

Comment: @Peter Good point! Meantime, the plug up there should be for 110V or 120V.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!